# 着 vs 衣 to refer to gi?

Tags: kanji, kanji-choice

When would I use 着（ki) as opposed to 衣 (i) to refer to a karate gi (空手着 or 空手衣)?

As I understand it, 着 refers to something you wear, literally being used as a noun for "suit of clothes" and being the root of "kimono."

衣 refers to clothing and is always a noun.

What is the usage case between the two? Is one more formal than the other, or more recognizable in writing?